# Google maps activity wont show in designer

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

the code runs with no error, but the designer gives me error and will not appear

[image]

`Cycle found (count=51) evaluating 'activity_nearby_places' with pathString="file:///c:/ path="C:\New folder (148)\GaspriceinEgypt\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_nearby_places.xml" stratIndex=3 suffixEndIndex=3 separator='\\"(parserfile=file:\\\\ C:\New folder (148)\GaspriceinEgypt\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_nearby_places.xml)`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".NearbyPlaces"
  tools:layout="@layout/activity_nearby_places" />
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have created a recurring loop / Cycle.

The `tools:layout` should not be reffering to the file you are in, but instead, some example layout file that you want the designer to display.

From the docs: `This attribute declares which layout you want the layout preview to draw inside the fragment (because the layout preview cannot execute the activity code that normally applies the layout).`

Try deleting the  `tools:layout=` line. or putting something more appropriate inside it.

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#toolslayout

Comment: give me example please
i delete the line tools:layout give me another error android studio add it

Comment: when delete this line give me unknown fragments error

Comment: if you follow the link, it explains how it is used for preview. insert a layout that is valid. Did you delete the end tag by mistake, as its on the same line? Hard to tell whats wrong now, wihtout the new error, and complete layout code. Your best bet is creating a new blank layout, and linking to that.

Comment: exmple code please i  remove this line without delete end tag give me unknown fragment
thank you so much

Comment: link put the file name of layout

Comment: The link puts the file name of a **Different** layout. Which is the key part in all this. it is what is causing the error, as you have put the name of the same layout.